# Sometime image are not accessing from assets folder in angular 5

Tags: angular5

I am building a angular 5 application .. I have bind src in component.html like this

`<img id='img-upload' [(src)] = "imgesrc"/>`

and my component.ts look like this

```
   ngOnInit() {
            this.footerService.messages.subscribe(msg => {
                console.log(msg);
                if (msg['value']) {
                    this.footerContent = msg["value"]['f_content']
                    this.imgesrc = "/assets/uploads/" + msg["value"]['f_logo']
                }
           })
       }
```

Actually data is binding in two way but when ng server is running and uploading to assets folder from node server , that file is not getting instead file is available  but when i am re building  with ng serve command that  image is appearing with same url which was  throwing a 404 error before  re build

Answer (score 1):

If you use `require('img_uri')`, I think your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks for replying .. Actually  i had solved it .. I  defined a  node server's  static folder and named as public  , then  in angualr i define a path to  public folder now i  use [src] path  as  node's public folder  instead  of  angualr  assets  folder  .. problem was  once app build then   it will  not recognize new changes like dynamically   bind  path